# Accessing Clipboard in Python version 3.1

Tags: python, clipboard

I want to access the clipboard using Python 3.1. I've obviously come across win32clipboard, but it requires pywin32 and in its site I only found download versions for up to Python 2.13 or so.

Bottom line: Is there a way to access the clipboard in Python 3.1 or do I have to revert to an old Python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to revert, it will be quite strange. Go to **http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/** and download package for Python 3.1 from there.

Comment: Gosh, I actually missed the 3.1 link when I looked! Thanks! =)